# atomically changing multiple rows in mySQL

Tags: mysql, atomic-swap

I have a mySQL table of the form

`entryID (PK), UserID, entryName`

Each user (as defined by his userID) may create any number of entries in this table, but for each user, the entryName must be unique. I would like to allow users to modify all of their entryNames at once. As such, I will present the user with a form with multiple entryName fields which they can edit.

The trouble is when trying to commit this to the database. I can't just update row by row as the case:

```
1, 1, Entry1
2, 1, Entry2
```

becoming

```
1, 1, Entry2
2, 1, Entry3
```

would cause an error when trying to rename Entry1 to Entry2. Currently, I read all rows with the given UserID, then delete them, and recreate each row. This works. The trouble with that method, however, is that if a user manages to cause an error in my script, ALL of his entries get deleted... and lost. And this is a Bad Thing. How would one solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical scenario for a TRANSACTION WITH ROLLBACK on EXCEPTION.

You can start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html